# Where do you put the gate-protection zener diode in an NMOS H-Bridge?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, zener

Do you even include it for an NMOS H-bridge?

Because typically I've only ever seen them in NMOS/PMOS bridges, not full NMOS bridges.

(Inductive load)

[image]

The protection zeners would go here right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they will work fine in those positions (preferably with a small gate resistor). It is the gate-to-source voltage you're trying to limit, so it makes sense to connect the zener directly from the gate to the source.

You can also use unipolar (or bipolar, as far as protecting the MOSFET goes) TVS diodes instead of zeners.